Is a *magnetized* ferrite less ideal as a core?
I have access to plenty of magnetized semi-toroidal (flat on top/bottom) ferrites and no non-magnetized ones. The poles of the magnetized ones are normal to the plane of magnets. Now if I were to use such a magnetized ferrite as a toroidal core, with the alternating magnetic fields being normal to the permanent one, 1- would it underperform as compared to a non-magnetized ferrite of the same shape? 2- would it be any better than vacuum?
P.S. Before jumping the gun, please note that this is irrelevant to this question.
P.S.2 Winding a toroid is time consuming so it's not easy to test #2 experimentally, especially since I don't have access to high current sources (>10A) or ultra precise devices.
Update/Clarification
Thanks to Jos for his invaluable feedback in regards to soft vs. hard ferrites and frequency dependence of their design. To bring closure to the issue (marking an answer as accepted), I'm looking for a definitive answer to this final piece of the puzzle - as I mentioned in the comments: Whether magnetizing an already magnetized ferrite orthogonal to its current poles takes more gauss/energy/time than a non-magnetized one (randomly aligned domains). The answer would be trivial if it was simply the opposite the direction, but not sure about the orthogonal case. With randomly aligned domains, more domains are already in the new/orthogonal direction, but nearly also as much right opposite to it (, otherwise it would be magnetized). So maybe the answer to this specific case is "no" on that basis?!

Whether any of the possible solutions would be "better" depends on the precise objective: are you interested in maximizing the inductance for a give number of turns? Or minimizing the losses for a certain required inductance? Or just to create some high AC impedance, e.g. for interference suppression?
In any case the material used for magnetized ferrite applications (hard ferrites) is not the same as the most favorable types for magnetic cores (soft ferrites). So the result will always be sub-optimal if you want to create a high-Q-factor inductor.
For interference suppression (where losses are in fact welcome) it could still be a good solution, at least better than air. For other purposes it is harder to say, because even the soft ferrites all have their specific frequency range and field strength restrictions, so you always need to check three things:

the $\mu_\text{r}$ value at the frequency of interest (you can only expect a reduction of the required number of turns by $\sqrt{\mu_\text{r}}$).
the $Q$ value (derivable from the loss-angle) at the frequency of interest (the final inductor $Q$ will be even lower than that due to resistive losses in the windings.)
The maximum field before saturation sets in (combined with the Ampere-turns that you want to use this will show you whether the material keeps its properties).

So unfortunately the question does not have one simple answer.

Thank you for the guidance. Unfortunately I don't have enough points to upvote. My case of interest is for current measurement of a home appliance (50/60 Hz).

So you want to make a current transformer, I presume. That just requires a high impedance (much like an interference suppressor) so I think the material, whatever its properties, will give you a better result than air (actually air can be used, see "Rogowski coil"). But of course to get a very accurate current transformer you would need a high-$\mu$ material (to make the coupling factor high). Without that, you can't be sure the current ratio is exactly $n_1:n_2$, you would have to calibrate that somehow.
(And I still think it would be better to demagnetize the material first...)

Well... I don't know what exactly to call it, but the shape of it resembles a current transformer as shown in wikipedia. However, I'll be measuring the voltage across the secondary. One thing I am still curious about much more in theory than simply the problem at hand: Whether magnetizing an already magnetized ferrite orthogonal to its current poles takes more gauss/energy/time than a non-magnetized one (randomly aligned domains). The answer would be trivial if it was simply the opposite the direction, but not sure about the orthogonal case.

With randomly aligned domains, more domains are already in the new/orthogonal direction, but nearly also as much right opposite to it. So maybe the answer is "no" on that basis?!

*1 in general, yes, as it will saturate more easily, though it should demagnetise over time and should be ok long term-this might mean that a circuit may have to be recalibrated after a while as the core demagnetises however
*2 it really depends on the application; each option has it’s own benefits, though if I may ask, why not use a steel core or air core?
